# call ajax page in current ajax page

Tags: javascript, ajax

i created two page "index.php" & "library.php" in the index.php page i include library page in a div using ajax.the problam is when i call library.php page in index.php the ajax which is exist library.php is not working.please help......

here is my code

Index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">
var rootdomain = "http://" + window.location.hostname

function ajaxinclude(url) {
    var page_request = false
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) page_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    } else return false
    page_request.open('GET', url, false)
    page_request.send(null)
    writecontent(page_request)
}

function writecontent(page_request) {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("http") == -1 || page_request.status == 200) document.write(page_request.responseText)
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div style="width:400px; height:500px;">
<script type="text/javascript">
ajaxinclude("Library.php")
</script>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Library.php

(include in index.php page)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">

        <title>Tabs - jQuery plugin for accessible, unobtrusive tabs</title>

        <script src="javascript/jquery-1.1.3.1.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="javascript/jquery.history_remote.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="javascript/jquery.tabs.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.tabs.css" type="text/css" media="print, projection, screen">

        <style type="text/css" media="screen, projection">



        body {
            font-size: 16px;  }
        * html body {
            font-size: 100%; 
        }
        body * {
            font-size: 87.5%;
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Trebuchet, Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        body * * {
            font-size: 100%;
        }
        h1 {
            margin: 1em 0 1.5em;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
        h2 {
            margin: 2em 0 1.5em;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        p {
            margin: 0;
        }
        pre, pre+p, p+p {
            margin: 1em 0 0;
        }
        code {
            font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h2>Slide and Fade Effect Combined</h2>

    <div id="container-5">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#fragment-13"><span>One</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-14"><span>Two</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-15"><span>Three</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="fragment-13">
            <p>Use a combined slide and fade effect to switch tabs:</p>
            <pre><code>$(&#039;#container&#039;).tabs({ fxSlide: true, fxFade: true, fxSpeed: 'fast' });</code></pre>
        </div>
        <div id="fragment-14">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
        <div id="fragment-15">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
          $('#container-5').tabs({ fxSlide: true, fxFade: true, fxSpeed: 'normal' });
        });
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not going to break into your computer to steal your code and debug it.

Comment: @blender, you need to post on debug-ninja.stackoverflow.com for that to happen

Comment: (disappears into the night, silently debugging the code of unaware victims). (Batman orchestral music fades in).

Answer (score 0):

after reading your code, it looks like you want to add a page in an existing page, then why you are using those ... again ?
Just try with the plain text ! no html, head !
script, and style can be used :)

you can use this jQuery code

```
$("#targetDiv").load("library.php");
```

**`Edit 2`**
try jQuery with this Library.php

```
    <script src="javascript/jquery-1.1.3.1.pack.js" type="text/javascript"/>
    <script src="javascript/jquery.history_remote.pack.js" type="text/javascript" />
    <script src="javascript/jquery.tabs.pack.js" type="text/javascript"   />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.tabs.css" type="text/css" media="print,  projection, screen">
    <style type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
    body {
        font-size: 16px;  }
    * html body {
        font-size: 100%; 
    }
    body * {
        font-size: 87.5%;
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Trebuchet, Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    body * * {
        font-size: 100%;
    }
    h1 {
        margin: 1em 0 1.5em;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    h2 {
        margin: 2em 0 1.5em;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    p {
        margin: 0;
    }
    pre, pre+p, p+p {
        margin: 1em 0 0;
    }
    code {
        font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Slide and Fade Effect Combined</h2>

<div id="container-5">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#fragment-13"><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-14"><span>Two</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-15"><span>Three</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="fragment-13">
        <p>Use a combined slide and fade effect to switch tabs:</p>
        <pre><code>$(&#039;#container&#039;).tabs({ fxSlide: true, fxFade: true, fxSpeed: 'fast' });</code></pre>
    </div>
    <div id="fragment-14">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    </div>
    <div id="fragment-15">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('#container-5').tabs({ fxSlide: true, fxFade: true, fxSpeed: 'normal' });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i try which u mention it's not work i can't understand why ajax not working..pls explain

Comment: do you want to show LIBRAY.PHP in INDEX.PHP ? What error you are getting ?

Comment: library.php is a tabbed panal the tab name are one,two,three but when i show library.php in index.php it's not come in tab form it's come just like not using ajax file it means that javascript is not working when i call library.php in index.php

Comment: $("#targetDiv").load("library.php"); it's become the same problam